# Running a cURL command in a Docker build

Tags: curl, jar, dockerfile

I am trying to download a jacoco jar using cURL command and copy/save the jar to this destination folder: dir/tmp/

This is how the Dockerfile looks for the above part:

```
RUN rm -r dir/tmp | true
RUN mkdir dir/tmp | true
RUN echo "Downloading jacoco jars"
RUN curl "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.5/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar" -o dir/tmp/jacoco.agent.jar
RUN echo "Done Downloading jacoco jars"
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Failed to create the file dir/tmp: No such file or directory
>
> curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 984)

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the intermediate directory `dir` exists?  Can you post the complete Dockerfile?  Does removing the `| true` make a difference (did you mean `|| true`, and you do you really want to suppress errors)?

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir` command needs to pass `-p` to allow multi-directory creation, I have also made some rectifications to make it work as per your requirement:

```
RUN rm -rf dir/tmp
RUN mkdir -p dir/tmp
RUN echo "Downloading jacoco jars"
RUN curl "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.5/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar" -o dir/tmp/jacoco.agent.jar
RUN echo "Done Downloading jacoco jars"
```

Or:

```
RUN rm -rf dir/tmp \
    && mkdir -p dir/tmp \
    && echo "Downloading jacoco jars" \
    && curl "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.5/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar" -o dir/tmp/jacoco.agent.jar \
    && echo "Done Downloading jacoco jars"
```